# Android Studio - XML Editor autocomplete not working with new XML files

Tags: android, android-layout

[image showing no suggestions for xml autocompletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCYU9.png)

in Android Studio i created a new XML file

as you can see when i press ctrl+space for autocompletion it says no suggestions

i have tried all solutions for similar questions in Stack Overflow but none of them worked

is there any gradle dependency i can add?

thanks alot

Comment: try File -> Invalidate cache and restart :D

Comment: I think you should clean and rebuild the project. Or you can try to restart PC or android studio.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your project folder in file manager C:/Users/YourUserName/AndroidStudioProjects/YourProjectName
2. Delete .idea folder. search for *.iml files and delete all those
3. Return Back to Android Studio
4. Go to File>Invalidate and Restart
5. After Restart it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to solve this issue. Remove the cache of Android Studio form folder manually and the restart the Android Studio.

Everything working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete .idea folder and .iml files from the project, do Invalidate and Restart. 
This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are typing in your code before the last closing bracket >, for example:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"> // code needs to be typed before this bracket

//not here

</LinearLayout>
```